# How flexible would a Centaur's human half be? Could it turn around 180 degrees?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, fantasy-races, centaur, bones

Would it be possible for a centaur's human half to turn around 180 degrees, with similar flexibility to a bird's neck?

I know birds can turn their heads around about that much, and reach behind themselves to preen. There are also a couple of people on youtube who can turn their heads around seemingly 180 degrees.

So would it be possible for centaurs to turn around 180 degrees and reach behind themselves, like birds do when preening their backs or tails? Could they do this while having a torso that appears very human-like?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Per our [help], we want 1 question per post, no bonus questions. It would help if you could clarify the anatomy of your centaurs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant ''around 360 degrees'' most mammals can already turn their head 180

Comment: Given that centaurs are entirely fictional, surely their flexibility is entirely up to you? Do you _want_ them to be able to turn around like that? No problem! It is done! Would you rather they couldn't? That's fine too!

Comment: @PythonProgrammersaresouless Do you mean 90 degrees?

Comment: @StarfishPrime I was interested in whether a human-like figure could have the flexibility of a bird's neck, after thinking about centaurs.

Comment: How are your centaurs like? What's their anatomy? Does the human portion house any organs that would definitely be better off not being squished by the process of twisting around? How many vertebrae do they have? Studying how birds have such flexible necks and how that changes when instead of a head the vertebrae are connected to and supporting a ribcage (something that, by default, tends to limit sideways articulation) could do wonders to help you.

Comment: @ProjectApex I figure mostly the oesophagus and muscles. Maybe some small secondary lungs or airsacs, to justify ribs. Not sure how many vertebrae... what would fewer or more than humans have indicate?

Answer (score 1):

As you said that centaurs have very human like torso, therefore they can bend  their shoulders to about 90º and their head further 60º and their eyes further 20º.

But they cannot bend their head 180º like a bird.

Comment: For clarification, I actually said, "appears" very human like. It can still have a different spine and anatomy for flexibility.